# Override Google Maps places search box styling in jqm

Tags: css, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, css-position

I am trying to integrate [Google maps Places search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) into my jQuery Mobile App.

I've created a search box with preferred styling in jQuery Mobile. I would like to use this search box instead of standard google search box. But for some reason my search box styling is being over ridden by Google maps search box styling as you can see in the below image (1). Can someone please suggest me a way to achieve the desired result shown in image2. Please also find my complete code. I'd be grateful for anyone's help.

[image]

The below image (2) shows what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Desired Location box styling]

Complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Google maps source for places seearch box and map display on page initilization-->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

    <style>
        #map-page, #map_canvas { width: 100%; height: 80%; padding: 0; }

        .container_16, #set_location {
        z-index:1;
        }

        .container_16 .alpha { clear-left: 0; }

        .grid_3,.grid_13{ margin: 0; padding: 1.5% !important; border: 0; float: left; }

        .container_16 { overflow: hidden; }

        .container_16 .grid_3 { 
    width: 15.75% !important;
        }

        .container_16 .grid_13 { 
    width: 78.25% !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('search_location')); // pac-input changed to search_location
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });


  // [END region_getplaces]

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="map-page" data-url="map-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <div>
        <img id='houseid' style='width:120px; ' src="" alt="logo"/> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#popup_cancel" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class=" ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-right ui-btn-a">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class='container_16 ui-corner-all' style='background-color: white; z-index:1000000000 !important; ' >
    <div class='grid_3' style='padding-top:0% !important; padding-bottom:0% !important;'>
        <a id='location' style='padding: 0%; margin-top: 0.65em;' href="#" onclick='get_location()' class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-mini">
        <img id='location_img' style='width:20px; padding:5px;' src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSwWvXKHpBpZ04VsfcHHtdjyHWhOrNq1zjDPWKg4vrg35wiPD8S8DQBSg" alt="HouseID">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class='grid_13' style='padding-top:0% !important; padding-bottom:0% !important;'>
        <input id='search_location' type='search' style=''>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="map_canvas" style='padding:0%;'>
        <!-- map loads here... -->
    </div>
</div>



<div data-role="popup" id="popup_cancel" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;"> 
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a"> <!-- This div element is not allowing Google map to render -->
    <h1>Cancel ?</h1>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h5 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to cancel and go back?</h5>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-a ui-mini" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-a ui-mini" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove line 51:

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

The purpose of this line is to embed the element "input" into the map at a specific location, "TOP_LEFT". [See google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlPositioning). I trialed your code with this commented out, and observed the result you were seeking.